# Visual Studio Extension Code-/Editorstyle

Tags: visual-studio, styles, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to apply my own .editorconfig or visualstudio settings to files without it messing up source control.
Essentially i just don't want braces on a new line, but at work our team uses that style and i obviously can't check in every file that i edit with 50 changes just because my settings are different.

Not being able to google this extension in 2 minutes makes me doubt its existence though. Would an extension like this be hard to write? I can't imagine it not existing if it wouldn't be.

Can't i just make a temp copy of the .cs file once i open it, apply my "personal code style" to that file, work, and once i save i save to the actual file using the "team code style"?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but: Why not just adopt the coding standards of the project? Standards like `.editorconfig` work with Visual Studio to help enforce those standards. Is the issue that you don't like the look of the preferred style, and would rather it be displayed per your preferences, while acknowledging the importance of a consistent coding style across the project?

Comment: Yes. The whole point of my question is, that i'd like it to just look different in my environment while not messing with the uniform style.

Comment: You should check whether [Resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1NPKxbCw6AIVUbaWCh0rVw7uEAAYASAAEgJOEvD_BwE) does work.